# Could not click on .gif file to generate the report

Tags: python, selenium, tabs, webdriver

I tried to use webdriver to automatically download the report.

Here what I have tried so far:

```js
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Kob/Desktop/Python projects/Chrome webdriver/Chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www2.ops3.moc.go.th/")

main_window = driver.window_handles[0]
new_window1 = driver.window_handles[1]
new_window2 = driver.window_handles[2]

Export = driver.find_element_by_link_text("EXPORT")
Export.click()

driver.switch_to.window(new_window1)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(new_window2)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(main_window)

driver.switch_to.frame("data")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

Commodity = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Commodity")
Commodity.click()

Year = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("q_Year"));
Month = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("q_Month"));
Currency = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("q_currency"));

Year.select_by_index("0")
Month.select_by_index("1")
Currency.select_by_index("1")

hscode = driver.find_element_by_name("q_hsList")
hscode.send_keys("8507")

driver.execute_script("doReport()")
driver.find_element_by_id("exportdlgImage").click()
```

With this code, I got this error message in return.

```js
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"exportdlgImage"}
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

**Questions**

1. Did the error message occur because the browser acknowledge that it was still working on the first tab or I did something wrong on finding the .gif file?
2. How could I move between tabs in the same browser? I did some research on this, but I found only sending crtl+t key and page up and down. I am not sure whether that solution can use in my case since when the script `doReport`was executed, it automatically generated a new tab.

Comment: What is `doReport()` exactly all about? Which element are you referring as `driver.find_element_by_id("exportdlgImage")`?

Comment: @DebanjanB As far as I know, the doReport() function is the command that generates another link showing report preview and link to download. For the second function (find_element_by_id), I attempted to find and clink the link to download this report. As you can see on the top-left of the screen(after you employ "doReport" function, there is an envelop picture which links to the link that download the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:** The error occurred because, as you mentioned in Question 2, `doReport` causes another tab to open. You must perform another `driver.switch_to.window()` after calling `doReport`.

**Question 2:** `driver.switch_to.window()` is the command that changes the interest of Selenium from one tab or window to another within the same browser instance.

Comment: Thank you Ron for your kind responses. Your answer on the second question is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

The report opens in a new window. You'll need to tell Selenium to switch to that window before you can interact with the elements in it:

```py
windows = driver.window_handles

driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("preview report").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.new_window_is_opened(windows))

new_window = list(set(windows) - set(driver.window_handles))[0]
driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
```

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for your kind help. I already tried your solution by inserting your code after mine, but the result was the same(I still could not switch to that window). I am sorry for my absurd python skill. What did I do wrong? Could you please explain more about your code? and do you have any further suggestion for regarding the same matter?. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you append your question with the updated script you tried as well the full console output (including error stack trace)?

Comment: Actually, after I have tried so hard on this, I can resolve the problem already. Thank you for your useful advice.